# How do I do addition on objects of type GLfloat in Python/PyOpenGL?

Tags: python, opengl, python-3.x, pyopengl

How do I do addition on objects of type GLfloat in Python/PyOpenGL?

```
$ python
Python 3.3.3 (default, Nov 26 2013, 13:33:18) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from OpenGL.GL import *
>>> GLfloat
<class 'ctypes.c_float'>
>>> a = GLfloat(0.0)
>>> a += GLfloat(1.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'c_float' and 'c_float'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

`GLfloat` is [ctypes.c_float](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_float).

Use [`value` attribute](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._SimpleCData.value):

```
>>> from OpenGL.GL import *
>>> a = GLfloat(0.0)
>>> a.value += 1
>>> a
c_float(1.0)
```

Comment: Is this the best way to do this?  Is it expensive?